# USB Keyboard not working after changing kernel config

Tags: module, linux-kernel, keyboard, usb, buildroot

Good Day Friends!
Using `buildroot 2022.11` I have tinkered with the kernel config and now any USB Keyboard are not working. There is no event message, no kernel message when plugged in. Nothing happens. It worked previously with 'Microsoft Wireless Desktop 900' keyboard.

On my device Radxa Zero SBC, ARM64 the keyboard is plugged in into one available USB 3.0, USB-C slot via USB-C to USB-A adapter.

I think that some USB3 options are missing but I can't figure out which one.
[Full Kernel config](https://pastebin.com/pDGfBZFM)

Comment: Do you have any other way to communicate with a shell on the system so that you can check things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USB controllers are not enabled in the kernel configuration. The following options should be set to `y` or `m`:

- `CONFIG_USB_DWC2`

  ```
     Device Drivers  --->
     [*] USB support  --->
         <*/m> DesignWare USB2 DRD Core Support
  ```
- `CONFIG_USB_DWC3`

  ```
     Device Drivers  --->
     [*] USB support  --->
         <*/m> DesignWare USB3 DRD Core Support
  ```

Comment: That's it! Thank you! DesignWare sounded to me like a manufacturer so I probably disabled it.